# Swift nested enums/structs to string in reverse order

Tags: swift, string, struct, enums

When using string keys in UserDefaults or any other service, it is a common practice to "."-separated words to build my keys. For example:

```
"com.domain.subdomain.scope.key"
```

Sometimes, we have multiples key names for a same scope or multiple scopes for a same subdomain (or whatever wording we want to use).

From a modelling perspective, this can be easily modelled with Structs or Enums:

```
struct Domain {
    struct SubdomainA {
        enum ScopeA {
            case keyA
            case keyB
            case keyC
            [...]
        }
        enum ScopeB {
            case keyA
            case keyB
            case keyC
            [...]
        }
        [...] // ScopeC
    }
    [...] // SubdomainB
}
```

Being able to run the autocomplete when writing stuff like:

```
let key = Domain.SubdomainB.ScopeC.keyB
```

Note that `key` is of type `Domain.SubdomainB.ScopeC`

### Question

Is there any easy way to use this code structure using enums or structs and then have a method that converts the whole thing into a string?

For example, let's imagine there is a method called `reverseStringValue` that does this job:

```
let key = Domain.SubdomainB.ScopeC.keyB.reverseStringValue
```

Note that this time we want `key` to be a `String`, and each component (word between ".") of this string is defined recursively by each struct/enum of the chain.

How would you approach this? (without overcomplicating it).

Thanks!